# No response for GRPC server using Kubernetes Ingress Nginx

Tags: kubernetes-helm, kubernetes-ingress, azure-aks

I am trying to deploy a GRPC based engine behind a Kubernetes Ingress-Nginx ingress, version 0.34.1 and I have already tested that it is working fine with a regular REST API setup, but I have had no luck in receiving any traffic from the backend GRPC when connecting from the port 50051. The backend GRPC itself contains a container that is listening on the port 50051 with the following configuration:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
name: microservice-one  
spec:
selector:
    matchLabels:
    app: microservice-one
template:
    metadata:
    labels:
        app: microservice-one
    spec:
    containers:
    - name: microservice
        image: azurecr.io/microservice:v1
        ports:
        - containerPort: 50051
        resources:
        requests:
            memory: "5G"
            cpu: 250m
        limits:
            cpu: 1000m
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
name: microservice-one  
spec:
type: ClusterIP
ports:
- protocol: TCP 
    port: 50051
selector:
    app: microservice-one
type: LoadBalancer
```

while the yaml file for my ingress applies the following configuration:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
name: service1
namespace: ingress
annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: "GRPC"
spec:
tls:
    - hosts:
    - [HOSTNAME]
    secretName: aks-ingress-tls
rules:
- host: [HOSTNAME]
- http:
    paths:
    - backend:
        serviceName: microservice-one
        servicePort: 50051
        path: /(.*)
```

However, upon testing and looking at the raw generated nginx configuration, with the irrelevant parts omitted below, I realized that the nginx server is only listening on port 443 and 80 as standard for an nginx config. I have read that the ingress only allows one port for https so I tried multiple different annotations (e.g. loadbalancer) that were said to bypass the limit but none of them have worked. Could anyone please advise on what other possible solutions there might be to the problem?

```
server {
    server_name [HOSTNAME] ;
    listen 80  ;
    listen 443  ssl http2 ;
    set $proxy_upstream_name "-";
    
    ssl_certificate_by_lua_block {
        certificate.call()
    }
    
    location / {
        set $namespace      "";
        set $ingress_name   "";
        set $service_name   "";
        set $service_port   "";
        set $location_path  "/";
        rewrite_by_lua_block {
            lua_ingress.rewrite({
                force_ssl_redirect = false,
                ssl_redirect = true,
                force_no_ssl_redirect = false,
                use_port_in_redirects = false,
            })
            balancer.rewrite()
            plugins.run()
        }
        port_in_redirect off;
        set $balancer_ewma_score -1;
        set $proxy_upstream_name "upstream-default-backend";
        set $proxy_host          $proxy_upstream_name;
        set $pass_access_scheme  $scheme;
        set $pass_server_port    $server_port;
        set $best_http_host      $http_host;
        set $pass_port           $pass_server_port;
        set $proxy_alternative_upstream_name "";
        client_max_body_size                    1m;
        
        grpc_set_header                        Upgrade           $http_upgrade;
        grpc_set_header                        Connection        $connection_upgrade;
        grpc_set_header X-Request-ID           $req_id;
        grpc_set_header X-Real-IP              $remote_addr;
        grpc_set_header X-Forwarded-For        $remote_addr;
        grpc_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto      $pass_access_scheme;
        grpc_set_header X-Forwarded-Host       $best_http_host;
        grpc_set_header X-Forwarded-Port       $pass_port;
        grpc_set_header X-Scheme               $pass_access_scheme;
        grpc_set_header X-Original-Forwarded-For $http_x_forwarded_for;
        grpc_set_header Proxy                  "";
        proxy_connect_timeout                   5s;
        proxy_send_timeout                      60s;
        proxy_read_timeout                      60s;
        proxy_buffering                         off;
        proxy_buffer_size                       4k;
        proxy_buffers                           4 4k;
        proxy_max_temp_file_size                1024m;
        proxy_request_buffering                 on;
        proxy_http_version                      1.1;
        proxy_cookie_domain                     off;
        proxy_cookie_path                       off;
        proxy_next_upstream                     error timeout;
        proxy_next_upstream_timeout             0;
        proxy_next_upstream_tries               3;
        proxy_pass http://upstream_balancer;
        proxy_redirect                          off;
    }
}
## end server [HOSTNAME]

## start server _
server {
    server_name _ ;
    listen 80 default_server reuseport backlog=511 ;
    listen 443 default_server reuseport backlog=511 ssl http2 ;
    set $proxy_upstream_name "-";
    
    ssl_certificate_by_lua_block {
        certificate.call()
    }
    
    location /(.*) {
        set $namespace      "myingress";
        set $ingress_name   "service1";
        set $service_name   "";
        set $service_port   "";
        set $location_path  "/(.*)";
        rewrite_by_lua_block {
            lua_ingress.rewrite({
                force_ssl_redirect = false,
                ssl_redirect = true,
                force_no_ssl_redirect = false,
                use_port_in_redirects = false,
            })
            balancer.rewrite()
            plugins.run()
        }
        
        port_in_redirect off;
        set $balancer_ewma_score -1;
        set $proxy_upstream_name "myingress-microservice-one-50051";
        set $proxy_host          $proxy_upstream_name;
        set $pass_access_scheme  $scheme;
        set $pass_server_port    $server_port;
        set $best_http_host      $http_host;
        set $pass_port           $pass_server_port;
        set $proxy_alternative_upstream_name "";

        grpc_set_header                        Upgrade           $http_upgrade;
        grpc_set_header                        Connection        $connection_upgrade;
        grpc_set_header X-Request-ID           $req_id;
        grpc_set_header X-Real-IP              $remote_addr;
        grpc_set_header X-Forwarded-For        $remote_addr;
        grpc_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto      $pass_access_scheme;
        grpc_set_header X-Forwarded-Host       $best_http_host;
        grpc_set_header X-Forwarded-Port       $pass_port;
        grpc_set_header X-Scheme               $pass_access_scheme;
        grpc_set_header X-Original-Forwarded-For $http_x_forwarded_for;
        grpc_set_header Proxy                  "";
        grpc_pass grpc://upstream_balancer;
        proxy_redirect                          off;
    }
```

Comment: why `microservice-one` svc has 2 types: `type: ClusterIP` and `type: LoadBalancer`? show get and describe svc output

Comment: It shows microservice-one  LoadBalancer   10.0.143.159   20.95.12.14   50051:31835/TCP   49s 

I was doing some testing and had forgotten to remove type: ClusterIP